# Unexpected token while using async await with babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, babeljs

Get unexpected token when using async/await with babel 6

boot.js

```
require("babel-core/register")({
  ignore: "./node_modules"
});
require("babel-polyfill");
```

asyncAwaitSample.js

```
async function() {
    await someAsyncAction();
  }()
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

And compiler is shooting error on string `async function() {`, it says " Unexpected token '{' "

Comment: put `()` around the function

Comment: I've tried, but it shoots error on `await someAsyncAction();` string then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you install `babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator`?

`npm install babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator`

and in your `.babelrc`

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-async-to-generator"]
}
```

source https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/

and then do:

```
(async function() {
  await someAsyncAction();
})()
```